# Changing the center of rotation using jQueryRotate plugin is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, rotation, jquery-rotate

Just trying to use the jQueryRotate plugin to rotate a `div`.

According to the docs (http://jqueryrotate.com), I should be able to use a `center` option to specify the center, but it's simply not working in Chrome, and I'm wondering if anyone has an idea why.

A simple test that should rotate `div` about the bottom right corner, but as you can in this fiddle, it still rotates it about the middle of the `div`: https://jsfiddle.net/7zm74ckk/1/

```
$("div").on("click", function() {
    $(this).rotate({
        animateTo: 90,
        center: [50,50]
    })
})
```

Note: I'm not looking for other methods to rotate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with `margin` and `padding` to achieve that!

See my [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/02x5a781/) or the snippet here

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
  $(this).rotate({
      angle: 0,
      center: [50, 50],
      animateTo:90
  })
})
```

```css
div .outer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

div .blue {
  margin: 130px;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wilq32/jqueryrotate/master/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```